# How to parse specific conents from table with Scrapy

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to parse certain contents from table looking like below:

```
<table class="dataTbl col-4">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Rent</th>
                            <td>5.5</td>
                            <th scope="row">Management</th>
                            <td>3.3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Deposit</th>
                            <td>No</td>
                            <th scope="row">Other</th>
                            <td>No</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Other2</th>
                            <td>No</td>
                            <th scope="row">Insurance</th>
                            <td>Yes</td>
                        </tr>
                                            </table>
```

My goal is to find specific row (for example, Rent) and if there is a match, extract the content in the next `<td>` tag(For example, 5.5).

But how can I do it in Python?

I'm using Python3/Scrapy 1.3.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [9]: Selector(text=html).xpath('//th[text()="Rent"]/following-sibling::td[1]').extract()
Out[9]: ['<td>5.5</td>']
```

1. Use `text()="Rent"` to id the `th` tag
2. Use `following-sibling::` get it's sibling and use `[1]` to get first

Comment: You are my hero today :) Thank you! By the way, if you know a good source for these techniques above, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Using a python's regular expression.

```
r'\>text\<.+\n +\<td\>(\d+\.\d+)'
```

In your case, change text by Rent. Also, [this](https://regex101.com/) is a useful web page to debug regular expressions.